# Taking input from a file with file lines grouped into pairs

Tags: python, file-io

So I have to read a file, and each time I read the file I have to take the lines in pairs and store the input in variables and do various things with the input data.

My question is how do I "group" the lines in pairs so that if, for instance, I take three of the persons favourite numbers on the first line, and their first and last name on the second line, and have this happen for the whole file? I have set it up to just print out the contents of what I am trying to store for simplicity.

```
array = []
userInput = sys.stdin
array.append(userInput.readline().strip())
firstName,lastName = map(str,userInput.readline().split(" "))

print(firstName)
print(lastName)
print(array)
```

An example of input would be:

```
1 2 3
John Doe
4 5 6
Queen Mary
```

An example of output in a text file would be:

```
John
Doe
['1 2 3']
Queen
Mary
['4 5 6']
```

Comment: See the `grouper` recipe in the [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes).

Answer (score 1):

You could `readline` twice in a loop and append them both to a data structure, etc...:

#### pseudocode

```
dataread = []

with open('file', 'r') as f:
    while f still has lines:
        twolines = [f.readline()]   # add strip/split as needed
        twolines.append(f.readline()) 
        dataread.append(twolines)
```

You will probably need to handle exceptions.

Once read, you can process each group of two lines in `dataread` the way you like.

Comment: `line` is already the first line; you only need one call to `f.readline()` (sorry, realized my first comment wasn't quite accurate).

Answer (score 0):

**Memory efficient solution**

Use a toggling flag which you toggle every second line and print content to output file (thus, your memory has to hold only the content of mximum 2 lines at a time):

```
with open('infile.txt') as in_file, 
    open('outfile.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        flag = 0
        for line in in_file:
            if not flag:
                s3 = [line]
                flag = 1
            else:
                s1, s2 = line.split()
                print(s1, end = "\n", file = out_file)
                print(s2, end = "\n", file = out_file)
                print(repr(s3), end = "\n", file = out_file)
                flag = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def read_lines_in_batches(file_path, n = 1):
    with open(file_path) as fh:
        fhs = [fh] * n
        for batch in zip_longest(*fhs):
            yield [line for line in batch if line]

for lines in read_lines_in_batches('foo/bar.txt', 3):
    print(lines)
```